# Make an automatic MCVE comment when closing as off-topic?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, minimal-reproducible-example, automatic-comments

When a question is no good without MCVE, I usually add a comment requesting it. However, formulating such a comment is a chore (I have to add that link to the page that describes what MCVE is), so I decided "let's vote to close it; the link will appear by itself".

However, when I voted to close the question, no comment appeared, just the button `close` changed to `close(1)`. I imagine that OP got no feedback at all: he **doesn't know** that his question is going to be closed soon unless he adds a MCVE.

It seems that this problem is easy to fix: make the system add an automatic comment.

> This question must include the desired behavior, a specific problem
>   or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it.
>   Please add these details to make the question useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example (add a link here - I am too lazy right now to dig it out for the 101th time!).

Advantages:

1. The user who votes to close doesn't need to look for the MCVE link
2. Even if the user who votes to close is lazy, OP knows that his question needs improvement
3. The comment is guaranteed to be polite

Disadvantages:

1. The comment is not specific; I can explain *why* MCVE is needed, but the automated system will only say that it's needed, possibly giving an impression that it's always needed.
2. The system may disclose too early who voted to close (?)

I suggest adding this feature.

Comment: The auto-comment, attributed to the first dupe closer, was always sort of a kludge. There's no reason for it to be a _comment_, it was just easier at the time than adding a purpose-built banner like we have now. If showing the potential close reasons to the asker before closure is desired, it should be done via that banner (only visible to the asker), not comments. I don't need my comment history littered with an auto-generated comment for every question I vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

What's actually unclear about the MCVE from the corresponding close reason?

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: **How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**.

Comment: "What's actually unclear about the MCVE from the corresponding close reason?" If this question is not rhetoric, I'll answer it - the unclear thing is that (I imagine) OP doesn't get this close reason until the question is closed, and then it's too late. Closed questions can be reopened, but helping OP prevent the closing is even better!

Comment: So you mean a similar behavior as with duplicate close votes/flags? Hmm, disputable. I'm leaving such comments asking for an MCVE also often, but not every time.

Comment: Frequently people are not asking for debugging help, they are asking for code to be written for them. For someone new to Stackoverflow the "*Questions seeking debugging help ...*" close reason bears no relation to what they were asking. They were not asking for debugging help, they were asking for code to be provided.

Comment: @AdrianHHH When they post code (off site the policies for an MCVE), they most likely want to have it debugged for either compiler errors or runtime errors (without showing efforts for any sufficient debgging method). So it has relation most of the time for my experience here.

Comment: Both close reasons are useful, the one in this answer and the one in the question. There are many questions asking for code, but nothing in the question to suggest they have tried themselves. I then think of someone new to Stackoverflow. They have written a very clear question with a clear statement of what is wanted, it just happens to be off topic. That needs a close reason that makes sense to that new user. There are several questions here on meta with variations on "*give me the code*", those I have read suggest close reasons that (in my opinion) will not be clear to the new user.